# XML - XSLT - for-each ordered by element position

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-3.0

I have the following XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<doc>
    <order>
        <oField name="YEAR"></oField>
        <oField name="MONTH"></oField>
        <oField name="DAY"></oField>
    </order>
    <noOrder>
        <noField name="MONTH"></noField>
        <noField name="YEAR"></noField>
        <noField name="DAY"></noField>
    </noOrder>
</doc>
```

And what I want to do is create a new element, that is sibling of `order` and `noOrder`, that basically gets the attributes from the `noField` elements but prints them based on their order in the upper `order` element. Maybe I'm being confusing, but here's the result XML document I want to get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<doc>
    <order>
        <oField name="YEAR"/>
        <oField name="MONTH"/>
        <oField name="DAY"/>
    </order>
    <noOrder>
        <noField name="MONTH"/>
        <noField name="YEAR"/>
        <noField name="DAY"/>
    </noOrder>
   <newOrder>
      <newOField>YEAR</newOField>
      <newOField>MONTH</newOField>
      <newOField>DAY</newOField>
   </newOrder>
</doc>
```

Note that the attribute `name` of both the `oField` and `noField` elements will be the same, but I don't want to get the data from the `oField` elements, which are already ordered. I want to get it from the `noField` elements,

This is the XSLT code I have so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:output indent="yes" cdata-section-elements="xml-property"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="doc/noOrder">
      <xsl:next-match/>
      <newOrder>
      <xsl:for-each select="noField">
          <!--<xsl:sort select="/doc/order/oField[position()]"/>-->
          <newOField>
              <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
          </newOField>
      </xsl:for-each>
      </newOrder>
  </xsl:template>    

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which produces the following result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<doc>
    <order>
        <oField name="YEAR"/>
        <oField name="MONTH"/>
        <oField name="DAY"/>
    </order>
    <noOrder>
        <noField name="MONTH"/>
        <noField name="YEAR"/>
        <noField name="DAY"/>
    </noOrder>
   <newOrder>
      <newOField>MONTH</newOField>
      <newOField>YEAR</newOField>
      <newOField>DAY</newOField>
   </newOrder>
</doc>
```

As you can see in my XSLT code in the commented line, I tried to set the `xsl:sort` element to sort by the `oField` elements, but since there are three of them, `/doc/order/oField[position()]` returns multiple values and the sorting can't be done (that is why the line is commented)

The simple solution would be to set the `xsl:for-each` by `oField` elements, but as I said before, that's not what I want,

Is there a way in XSLT to do this?

Thanks!

**EDIT/UPDATE**

Maybe the way I wrote the question made it a little confusing, but I want to get the data from the attributes in the  elements, and not the  elements. But as they are the same ( and  elements are exactly the same, with same attribute values), I want to print the values in the attributes (in the  elements, inside the  element) by the order they appear in the  elements, inside the  element

Thank you!

Alexandre Jacinto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an `index-of` function https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-index-of in XPath that I think you can use to compute the sort key based on the order of the other attribute values:

```
  <xsl:template match="doc/noOrder">
      <xsl:next-match/>
      <newOrder>
      <xsl:variable name="sort-order" select="../order/oField/@name"/>
      <xsl:for-each select="noField">
          <xsl:sort select="index-of($sort-order, @name)"/>
          <newOField>
              <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
          </newOField>
      </xsl:for-each>
      </newOrder>
  </xsl:template>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NzcBtg

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for, as I wanted to still get the values from the attributes the noField elements but in the order they appear in the oField elements. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I did correctly understand your question.
Try the following template, the output is as desired. It uses the `position()` of `noField` as index to `oField` and prints its `@name` attribute.

```
<xsl:template match="doc/noOrder">
    <xsl:next-match/>
    <newOrder>
      <xsl:for-each select="noField">
        <xsl:variable name="curPos" select="position()" />
        <newOField>
            <xsl:value-of select="/doc/order/oField[$curPos]/@name"/>
        </newOField>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </newOrder>
</xsl:template>
```

**Output is:**

```
...
<newOrder>
  <newOField>YEAR</newOField>
  <newOField>MONTH</newOField>
  <newOField>DAY</newOField>
</newOrder>
....
```

Comment: Thank you! In fact that produces the expected result. I am going to apply it to my real problem and I'll let you know if it works!

Comment: The thing was that I wanted to still get the data from the attributes in the <oField> elements and not from the <noField> elements. I am going to apply it to my real problem and I'll let you know if it works!

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="doc/noOrder">
        <xsl:next-match/>
        <newOrder>
        <xsl:for-each select="noField">
            <xsl:sort order="descending" select="@name"/>
            <newOField><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></newOField>
        </xsl:for-each>
        </newOrder>
    </xsl:template>
Try it.
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but that is basically sorting the elements by their alphabetical order, right?